# CSS rounded corner element fails in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11, css-shapes

I'm basically trying to do a "CSS-triangle" (you know, an element where the entire shape is generated using borders) but instead of a triangle shape, I want a square with rounded corners on the left side and straight corners on the right side.

This works fine in Chrome but IE11 creates a weird artefact at the top-left corner. (a background-colored oval right where the rounded corner should be. really strange!)

Is there a way to create a workaround for IE11?

```
.RoundedElement {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid #00a2d4;
  position: relative;
  right: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
 border-color: #F7A824;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbjaOG

Comment: Is there a reason not to simply use [border-radius with a background](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpdZom) ?

Comment: it shuold be supported from ie9 onward

Comment: It's even not working in FF also at my side.

Comment: The demo you shared seems not to be working as you describe, with Chrome. Can you share a sreenshot of the desired shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are over complicating the problem here.

Try the following:

```css
body { margin: 50px; }

.RoundedElement {
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  right: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
 background-color: #F7A824;
}
```

```html
<div class="RoundedElement">
</div>
```

Why not use the regular `background-color` with border radius that works by default ?

If you still want to use `border` try the following:

```css
body { margin: 50px; }

.RoundedElement {
  width: 20px; //Added 20px to fix in FF.
  height: 0px;
  border-top:30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 40px solid #00a2d4;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
  border-color: #F7A824;
}
```

```html
<div class="RoundedElement">
</div>
```

Comment: Ended up going with this answer since it was the closest to my original css  and the closest my original idea.

Answer (score 0):

tweaking the code to:

```
body { margin: 50px; }

.RoundedElement {
  width: 10px;
  height: 0;
  border-top:30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid #00a2d4;
  position: relative;
  right: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
  border-color: #F7A824;
  z-index:2
}
```

[**pen**](http://codepen.io/maio/pen/ZGbvov)

works in FF (should also in ie but not tested)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do it like this. Use `border-radius` (support [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius)). Also what you have is not a square, this is.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50% 0px 0px 50%;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It not work because your div size is 0:  width: 0; height: 0;

Comment: You pointed out the reason of the problem, you don't provide a way to solve it. You should improve your answer explaining how to do this.

Comment: Also this answer is wrong. The element can be 0x0 as the border is the thing doing the work,

Comment: @Ruddy - exactly. 
My original idea was to let the border do all the work so I was hoping the element could be 0x0